# Close meanmenu on menu links

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu

I'm using the meanmenu plugin. As directed by the page - I should put an option "onePage : true" but that doesn't work. I need the mobile menu to close when a link is selected.

At present menu is working but stays open until user clicks close button
If I click the X it closes menu ok.

How can close the menu when I click any of the menu links?

Here's the link to my page: http://54.169.61.153/teavana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hide on click event should do the work

```
$('.bigMenu li').click(function(){
  $('.bigMenu').hide();
  $('.meanmenu-reveal').removeClass('meanclose');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to keep the **slide animation** when hiding the menu use `slideUp()` function:

```
$('.bigMenu li').click(function(){
  $(".mean-nav ul:first").slideUp();
  $('.meanmenu-reveal').removeClass('meanclose');
});
```